# Error while implementing firebase in expo snack (react native)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, react-native-firebase

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGXq8.png)

I encounterd this error while importing firebase to my expo snack which is use for authentication in my app project. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with babel:
Try this first: `npm add @babel/runtime`
And if that doesn't work try to do this:

```
as was mentioned above, looks like the presence of this property
watchFolders: [${__dirname}/../..],
in metro.config.js solves the problem. I have a monorepo and mobile app is one of packages, that is why I need ../..

BTW in my case, interopRequireDefault problem appears only when I make a release build with

react-native run-android --variant release

developing mode ( react-native run-android ) works fine even without metro.config.js file
Also, there is no problem if a project is not configured as Monorepo
```

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27712